# I have a problem with jboss https listeners

Tags: https, jboss

This is the command I'm trying

```
standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=httpspriv:add(socket-binding="httpspriv", security-realm="SSLRealm", max-post-size="10485760")
```

This is the log that i get when i try to add a listener

```
"outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.undertow.listener.httpspriv is missing [jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.SSLRealm]"]},
    "rolled-back" => true
```

I already configured the https interface, im trying to add https listener in jboss client and this is the issue that i have.
I dont understand why its telling me that is missing if i didnt add yet.

Comment: What version of WildFly for JBoss EAP are you using? It looks like the `SSLRealm` has not been defined.

Comment: I'm using Wildfly 14.0.1 and i think that is not the problem because i added SSLRealm before with this command `/core-service=management/security-realm=SSLRealm:add()` And i configured before the http-default and httpspub with any problem.

Comment: What happens if you do `/core-service=management/security-realm=SSLRealm:read-resource`? Does it succeed? I'd also suggest looking at Elytron for the realm too. Newer versions of WildFly only support Elytron so it would be migration easier.